# Is it possible to get LineageOS working on Samsung Galaxy S6 T-Mobile USA (zerofltetmo, SM-G920)?

Tags: lineageos, samsung-galaxy-s-6

[LineageOS](https://download.lineageos.org/) offers an official [International Samsung Galaxy S6 build](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/zerofltexx/install), which does NOT install on the T-Mobile USA S6, but there's [an unofficial T-Mobile USA build](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/lineage-os-14-1-galaxy-s6-t-mobile-zerofltetmo-nougat-rom/) that does, but after [installing](https://www.droidviews.com/install-lineage-os-samsung-galaxy-s6/) it just [hangs on boot](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5tzafr/stuck_on_boot_animation/). (To install I used TWRP and adb sideloaded LineageOS, Stock Open gapps, SuperSU in that order)
Has anyone had success running LineageOS on the T-Mobile version of the S6?

Comment: Please tell us about the steps you've followed. Have you installed Unofficial TMobile build over LineageOS for S6?

Comment: @RahulGopi I installed the unofficial TMobile build + gapps + superSU over a fully wiped phone, using TWRP side-loading

Comment: This looks different than what Jonathan's links look like now, but I believe it's the same as these? [http://androidbiits.com/t-mobile-samsung-galaxy-s6-sm-g920t-android-7-1-1-nougat-lineageos-14-1-rom/](http://androidbiits.com/t-mobile-samsung-galaxy-s6-sm-g920t-android-7-1-1-nougat-lineageos-14-1-rom/)
("taste the tremendousness! Isn't it stunning?") [https://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/lineage-os-14-1-galaxy-s6-t-mobile-zerofltetmo-nougat-rom/](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/lineage-os-14-1-galaxy-s6-t-mobile-zerofltetmo-nougat-rom/) I haven't tested this either, and am loo

Answer (score 1):

I was able to [install this cryptic NexusOS version](https://stor.lukasberger.at/TeamNexus/Samsung/zero/) of LineageOS by [Team Nexus](http://nexus-roms.eu/).

I have no idea if it's safe, or a good ROM, The [github is here](https://github.com/TeamNexus/android_device_samsung_zero-common) but it's lacking information, an issues page, or a website on it, and it only seems to be referenced in broken english blogs, and scam searches appear when searching 
`nexus-roms.eu` on duckduckgo, and their site is down. So I would not recommend it.
It does seem to install & boot on the T-Mobile USA Samsung Galaxy S6

Answer (score 1):

I just installed LineageOS on my SM-G920T using this build from XDA:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/samsung-galaxy-s-6--s-6-edge-unified-development/rom-unofficial-lineageos-17-1-t4053959

I used the following resources:

- LineageOS multitarget: https://github.com/enesuzun2002/lineageos-ota/releases/download/lineage-17.1-20200413/LineageOS-10-zero-multitarget-2020-04-13_2047.zip
- Open Google Apps (Optional): https://opengapps.org (Select ARM64, Android 10 and choose the bundle you want, I used Stock)
- Magisk: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/download/v20.4/Magisk-v20.4.zip

In the end, the process was:

1. Install TWRP (https://twrp.me/):

- To install it, Firstly root the current ROM using https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/ I attempted to use the new version at firmware.mobi but had no success (the file was written correctly with ODIN, but it didn't install SU)
- Then install the TWRP APK from the Playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twrp.twrpapp)
- Follow the instructions to download the file for your S6 and then flash it to the recovery partition

2. Restart the phone in recovery mode (Vol Up + Home + Power)
3. Move the 2 or 3 zip files (LineageOS, Magisk, and GoogleApps) to your phone's internal memory or a mounted SD card
4. Wipe the Dalvik cache, system, data and cache partitions (do not wipe the internal storage or USB)
5. Install Lineage OS, Google Apps, and Magisk
6. Wipe the Dalvik cache again and reboot

The instructions from the XDA build do not mention installing Magisk but If I didn't install it both the 9.0 and 10.0 based builds failed to boot, I didn't install SuperSU but you shouldn't have trouble adding the zip to the install queue.